# Drop down menu in PHP file shows up looking messed up

Tags: php, html, css

Part of `main.php` content:

```php
<form class="formValidate" id="formValidate" method="post" action="routers/menu-router.php" novalidate="novalidate">

<?php
      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      
      if($row['deleted'] == 0){
            $t1 = 'selected';
            $t2 = '';
          }
          else{
            $t1 = '';
            $t2 = 'selected';            
          }
          echo '<select name="'.$row['id'].'_hide">
                      <option value="1"'.$t1.'>Available</option>
                      <option value="2"'.$t2.'>Not Available</option>
                    </select>';
        }
        ?>
</form>
```

This code shows a drop-down list for each item in my database table `items`.
It changes whether an item shows up on another page through changing its availability on this page. It works just fine but what I'm concerned with is how each drop-down list shows up on my page.

It shows up as follows (drop down list with contents showing on top):

[image: drop down list with contents showing on top]

Even if I try to change its style using CSS, barely anything changes (drop-down list with changed outline):

[image: drop-down list with changed outline]

I only want the last section to appear as the previous content does nothing.

Contents of `menu-router.php` for anyone interested:

```php
<?php
include '../includes/connect.php';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if(preg_match("/[0-9]+_hide/",$key)){
            if($_POST[$key] == 1){
            $key = strtok($key, '_');
            $sql = "UPDATE items SET deleted = 0 WHERE id = $key;";
            $con->query($sql);
            } else{
            $key = strtok($key, '_');
            $sql = "UPDATE items SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = $key;";
            $con->query($sql);          
            }
        }
    }
header("location: ../main.php");
?>
```

Comment: If the problem is the CSS styling of the HTML then the *database queries* don't really seem relevant.  Can you provide a [mcve] of the resulting HTML and CSS, and indicate how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL Injections! You should use _Prepared Statements_ or at least properly _escape_ the `$key` variable in your `UPDATE` statements! 
Anchor your regular expression with `^` and `$` so that only valid keys are processed.